# What font can be used as an alternative to Avenir Next Demi?

Tags: font-recommendation

Which google font is most similar to [Avenir Next Demi](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/avenir-next-pro/pro-demi/) bold?

[image]

Comment: Only you can decide which is most similar to you; this question smacks of not being bothered to look for yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi, welcome to our site! I have edited your question to fit better with our format. It's always helpful to provide links or images of what you're working with so that others don't have to go hunting for it

Comment: What aspect / trait / character of this font is it that you want to see back in your alternative?

Comment: are you looking for a FREE alternative- or is there any other reason why you dont want to use Avenir?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

### 1. Montserrat

Though recognizable in its own right, the popular Montserrat is probably the best replacement for Avenir.

[image: Montserrat vs. Avenir font comparison]

Avenir and Montserrat are both clean, geometric sans serif fonts with clean, simple letterforms and relaxed spacing. Avenir’s letterforms are a bit narrower on the whole. Since Montserrat is on Google Fonts, it’s particularly easy to use in your own project.

[image: Uppercase Montserrat vs. Avenir font comparison]

It’s worth noting that in uppercase, both the overall feel (Montserrat is punchy and stocky) and the unique letterforms of each (Avenir’s “Q”, Monserrat’s “G”) set the two apart a bit more.

What it’s got: 9 weights + italics

Get it at: [Montserrat at Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat)

## 2. Eau

The clean-cut Eau is a fantastic font on its own, and a great free alternative to Avenir.

[image: Eau vs. Avenir font comparison]

While Montserrat above is almost immediately recognizable in its own right, Eau is basically unused in the wild – and therefore makes a more interesting free alternative to Avenir.

[image: Uppercase Eau vs. Avenir font comparison]

On the whole, Eau has slightly narrower letterforms and a darker normal weight.

What it’s got: 3 weights + italics

Get it at: [Eau at Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/eau)

## Other Avenir alternatives

You can also check out [3 other Avenir alternatives](https://learnui.design/blog/avenir-similar-fonts.html), along with usage notes and download links.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Jost is a good alternative, they both had their design derive from Futura and have a similair double story a. Sadly it is purely geometric and doesn't have neo-grotesk-equse letters. If you really need the lowercase T of Avenir in your alternative go use League Spartan with a alternate lowercase A and U.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try using Identifont's Similar Font Finder: http://www.identifont.com/find?similar=Avenir+Next&q=Go